# How to disable parent directory access in web file browsing without web server

Tags: html

I am writing a command line application that produces an index.html with links to other generated HTML files, but also some links to filesystem subdirectories. Here is an example of such a link:

```
  <a href=../../invoices class="btn btn-primary">Invoices</a>
```

The intention for sharing this content is for the user to zip up the directory tree and send it to other parties for review. However, some users might think to use `ngrok`, or use screen sharing, to share their web browser to allow other people to access their local system. With `ngrok` they would be running a web server and might be able to configure the web server to protect against this, but with screen sharing that would not be possible. (Consider the case where a user might leave their web browser open to the remote user and step away, not realizing that the remote user can now examine their entire filesystem.)

The problem is the "Parent Directory" links. Using those links, the others could navigate above the intended directory root and navigate their entire filesystem. Here is an image to illustrate:

[image]

The directories linked to can have arbitrary numbers and levels of subdirectories, so hard-coding links on custom pages would probably be prohibitively complicated.

There is no web server involved here; the files are displayed by just opening `index.html` in a web browser, so `.htaccess` is not a solution. Also, I don't want to disable navigation, I only want to limit its upper bound.

Is there a way to prevent this access?

Comment: Please tag your language and post some relevant code. Your question is too broad as it is.

Comment: I've added a sample of the HTML code, and an illustration of the rendered code. I don't think this has anything to do with the language that generated the HTML. Once you click on a file link, the browser has control, and you can continually click the Parent Directory link until reaching the top (root directory)...and from there go anywhere in the filesystem.

Comment: If you're asking for a browser solution, tag JavaScript and show some effort. Also make it more clear what behavior you're trying to prohibit. Keep in mind that anyone can bypass such a strategy with the address bar.

Comment: Regarding "tag JavaScript and show some effort", that's incredibly rude, and assumes that I have the knowledge, interest, and time to accomplish that. I don't need your help if it is delivered with disrespect.

Comment: I've clarified my concern by adding a mention of screen sharing to the question.

Comment: Call it rude if you like, but it's what's expected. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. We're not a discussion forum, so you need to provide a basis for answers.

Comment: Regarding "make it more clear what behavior you're trying to prohibit", I posted:

"The problem is the "Parent Directory" links. Using those links, the others could navigate above the intended directory root and navigate their entire filesystem."

I am willing to elaborate on that if you can help me understand what is unclear.

Comment: Also, your statement "Please tag your language and post some relevant code." makes me wonder if you did not completely understand my question. The question was about the browser's treatment of an anchor link to the filesystem. At that point, my code is not active, and the browser is in full control. I was asking how to impose a constraint on the browser. I did tag HTML. An additional language would be misleading, because it's the HTML that is the issue here.

Comment: Keith, flag as you see fit, but don't call users out in the comments. Also, a lot has changed in the question since my first comments, but the situation is still somewhat vague, as evidenced by the lack of response. We'd like to help, but I'm not even sure what to ask since I'm not sure what your goal is from a technical standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no web server involved at all, there is no way to prevent that behaviour.
Edit:
You could of course write a browser plugin that limits the access to the parent directory using JavaScript. But every client would have to install that plugin.

Comment: As mentioned above, I don't think this has anything to do with the language or the script that generated the HTML. Once you click on a file link, the browser has control, and you can continually click the Parent Directory link until reaching the top (root directory)...and from there go anywhere in the filesystem.

Comment: @KeithBennett In the HTML file you can only click on the links that are there, and if there is no link to the parent directory, because the script filtered it out, you cannot click on it.

Comment: I appreciate your trying to help, but I don't think you're understanding; at the point this is a problem, the page being shown is not produced by my script, it's a special file browsing page created by the web browser itself. You can simulate it by typing `file:///` in your browser's address bar. There is no HTML at all. My HTML has a link to a directory, and once the user clicks on that link, the browser does its own thing, it is not getting instructions from any HTML file.

Comment: @KeithBennett ah ok, i misunderstood you then. If it is like that, __what you want to achieve is not possible__ !

Comment: Thank you. I wonder though, if any browser software has command line flags or other configuration options to limit its view rights to a specific directory and below? Or some JavaScript control that does file browsing that can impose this constraint?

Comment: @KeithBennett about the command line flags and configuration i do not know, but i do not think so, and about the JavaScript see my edited answer.

Comment: Regarding the JavaScript, I was thinking of maybe a third party JS component that I could load from my HTML page, and pass control to that instead of using a filesystem anchor tag, rather than a browser plugin. Also, it would be nice to keep the parent directory option, but only until reaching a specified directory.